# readRDS error from reading a R object of ~ 160MB

Tags: r

I’m trying to save a R object, which is a linear regression model based on ridge regression using R package `glmnet`. I'm using `saveRDS` to save it and it runs without error.

```
saveRDS(ridge, file = 'rnaClassifer_ridgeReg.RDdata')
```

HOWEVER, I cannot load the object back to R studio via `readRDS`, and it keeps giving errors and crashes the R session.

```
readRDS('rnaClassifer_ridgeReg.RDdata')
```

Note here this is a R object with size of 161MB after saving as `rnaClassifer_ridgeReg.RDdata` (which can be downloaded from [here](https://miscellaneous-hw.s3.us-west-004.backblazeb2.com/rnaClassifer_ridgeReg.RDdata)). My local laptop has 8 cores / 32 GB, which I would think is enough?

Here I'm also attaching the dataset ([here](https://f004.backblazeb2.com/file/miscellaneous-hw/data.txt.gz)) used to build the regression model, along with the code. Feel free to run the commands below to generate the R object `ridge`, and see if you can save it and load it successfully back to R.

```
library (caret)
library (glmnet) 

data.lm.train = read.table('data.txt.gz', header = T, sep = '\t', quote = '', check.names = F)

lambda <- 10^seq(-3, 3, length = 100)
### ridge regression
set.seed(666)
ridge <- train(
  dnaScore ~., data = data.lm.train, method = "glmnet",
  trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),
  tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0, lambda = lambda)
)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What specific errors are you receiving? Typically, RDS files should use `RDS` extension to avoid the environment/image RData outputs with `save()`.

Comment: I get "Error: C stack usage  7969376 is too close to the limit", memory usage barely budged (r-devel, Linux, 64G available)

Comment: @Parfait, the error is "R session aborted. R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated". Whether I'm using RDS or RData as extension, it makes no difference. And I confirmed save/read files area indeed consistent. The reason I'm providing a link is to ensure I can provide the entire file as example, not smaller sized version. Smaller sized file might not be able to produce the error I'm facing here if it's related to memory.

Comment: @BenBolker , what do you think the error msg is suggesting? Any solution?

Comment: *which is a linear regression model based on ridge regression* ... Please show the code in how that object is created. Include all `library` lines.

Comment: @Parfait, I just modified the original post to include all info needed to reproduce the error. Thanks!

Comment: @Parfait, not pushing at all, but curious if you have ever had a chance to try out the code yet? THANKS A LOT!